# lock tables sql+php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to lock a table before doing the action on the table in PDO, so two users will not be able to do the same action in the same time.

I tried as follow:

```
$this -> link ->beginTransaction();
$this -> link ->exec('LOCK TABLES `MYTABLE` WRITE;');
//do something...
$this -> link ->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
$this -> link ->commit();
```

but if two users try this query, they both stack.
what I do wrong?

thanks!!

Comment: Is it necessary to lock the table during a transaction?

Comment: Why do you want to lock the table?

Comment: I want to avoid a case that both users will do it in the same time,
for example register with same username.
although it's a key in the table, it mess up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$this->link->beginTransaction();
$this->link->query('select yourcolumn from yourtable where yourcondition for update');
sleep(20);
$this->link->commit();
```

Then open mysql workbench and try run the following

```
begin;
select count(yourcolumn) from yourtable where yourcondition for update;
// will lock here
```

Just remember ALWAYS open transaction AND use select for update when selecting the column data

I have tested the following, which is also protected by locking, when you run the following in workbench (while the above php script is running)

```
update yourtable set yourcolumn=yourvalue where yourcondition;
// will lock here because php has obtained lock, no need to use transaction here
```

However, the following is NOT protected by locking, when you run the following in workbench (while the above php scriptis running)

```
select yourcolumn from yourtable where yourcondition;
// will immediately return resulset because you are not using transaction AND "for update"
```

In addition, you may have a look at all your codes where beginTransaction is used, because long running transaction will cuase long table locking. An example is you only a transaction in an import file operation. Table will be locked after you insert the first record into table.

```
begin;
insert into yourtable values yourvalues;
// will acquire lock here, other mysql workbench will be deadlock
// until your whole import operation is done and rollback/commit your upload
```